# SharePoint 2010 solution package not deploying to all servers

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, solution-deployment

Having an issue with deploying a WSP to our farm (2 WFEs, 2 App servers). When I try to run `Install-SPSolution <packagename> -WebApplication <appurl> -GACDeployment -Force`, the timer jobs for deploying the solution are created on all the servers except for one App server (coincidentally or not, the server on which Central Admin is running).

Checked the configuration - the Web Application service is running on all servers (one of the solutions suggested). Tried restarting `SPTimerV4`, clearing the configuration cache, restarting IIS, restarting `SPAdminV4`, rebooting the server - nothing seems to get the solution installed on that one server, and I'm really at a loss for what to do next.

Comment: Are you running the command from the CA? Are the solution scoped for a single web application?

Comment: Ran the command from both the CA and from a different server on the farm - either way, the CA server wasn't getting the deployment timer job. Also, all features are Web Application scoped or lower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much beating of head and hours of Support time from MS, we determined that the Config Refresh and Timer Job Refresh jobs were missing from the affected server. The solution, therefore was to remove the server from the farm and rejoin it. Once we did that, the solution package deployed without any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the Services (service.msc), check if Sharepoint Admin Service and Sharepoint Timer Job service is running.

Comment: As mentioned in OP, both SPTimerV4 and SPAdmin services were restarted prior to running install.

Answer (score 0):

In Our Case, Solutions were deployed into Web Server but not on the App Server due to which `Test-SPContentdatabase` shows up error message related to the solutions that are not installed in Application Server. We faced this issue when we were upgrading our Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2010 environment

Cause: 
Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Web Application Stuck on Starting in Application Server

Solution: Stopped and Started Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Web Application which resolved the issue:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following troubleshooting steps to resolve this problem:

1. Execute `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs` on your Central Administration server.
2. and / or execute `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs` on all the servers in the SharePoint farm.
3. and / or restart the SharePoint Timer Service on all servers in the SharePoint farm.
4. and / or check that all the servers in the SharePoint farm are using the same time zone.
5. and / or delete the deployment timer job that is causing the problem.